# Not able to connect to internet using chrome

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, firefox

I am not able to connect to the internet using my chrome and opera browser while I am able to browse perfectly using Firefox.I am using Windows 7 and my connection is ADSL and using a Netgear wireless router

Comment: Is this for all sites?

Answer (score 2):

Is the Windows Firewall blocking the outgoing connections?

I don't have Windows 7 installed on this machine so I can't check the options you need, but check that it's set to "ask" or "prompt" when a new program tries to make an outgoing connection.

If it is set that way check the current rules to see if Chrome and Opera have been blocked.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the Proxy settings?

**Options -> Under the hood -> change proxy settings**

If you're using it at home probably you just habe to clear al the proxy settings